# System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'MyRecord' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to connect to a SQL Server database from my MVC app. I keep getting this error:

System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'MyRecord' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. I googled it and founf that this error occurs when one did not define get and set for the key inside the class. That's not true in my case since I have them defined. Below is my sample class:

```
[Table("DataRecords")]
public class MyRecord
{
    public string RecordID { get; set; }
    public string RecordDesc { get; set; }
    public float PageNo { get; set; }

}
```

I also have MyRecordContext class:

```
public class MyRecordContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyRecord> MyRecords { get; set; }
}
```

And a controller with "Details" action:

```
 public ActionResult Details(string _id)
 {
        MyRecordContext rc = new MyRecordContext(); <-- ERROR HERE

        MyRecord r = rc.MyRecords.Single(x => x.RecordID == _id);

        return View(r);
  }
```

I call it as : http://localhost:57802/Home/Details/01-019-2-1111-00-00

Can anyone help diagnose the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you the exact problem. There's no key defined on your entity. Entity Framework uses certain conventions to automatically decipher which property should be the primary key, however, since your entity here is named `MyRecord`, EF will look for a property named something like `MyRecordID`, not `RecordID`. If your class and/or property name does not conform to conventions, then you have to tell EF explictly what to use:

```
[Key]
public string RecordID { get; set; }
```

**UPDATE**

If you have a composite key, then, you just have to specify the column order as well:

```
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public int Key1 { get; set; }

[Key, Column(Order = 2)]
public int Key2 { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for fast response! What do I do in case my primary key is a composite key?

Comment: I tried adding attribute [Key] and the error is "The type or namespace 'Key' could not be found"

Comment: Then add the namespace. Visual Studio should be able to resolve if for you by just right-clicking "Key" and going into the "Resolve" item in the context menu. The namespace is `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`, just for reference, though.

Comment: Thank you! Now I have noticed when debugging that the argument string _id in my controller is null. What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: Check your routes. The default route uses `id`, not `_id`, so unless you have actually created a route that specifically accepts `_id`, the routing framework has no way to know what part of the URL you're expecting `_id` to come from.

Comment: I am new to MVC. So the parameter of the Action method should always be the default that is found in RouteConfig?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can add additional routes as needed. Or you can use attribute routing to define what parameters the URL should accept on an action by action basis. However, if you rely on the default route only, then yes, your action must accept `id`, since that is the only thing defined for the default route.